# Difference vulnerability between .net core and .net framework

Tags: .net, security, .net-core, nuget

I don't understand why with the old .net Framework, the recomandation for vulnerability is to update only windows and not the nuget package.
But for the .net core, the recommandation is to update nuget package.
I search are an article that explain the difference between fix vulnerability between .net core and .net framwork.

Sample:

https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-8421/ (only update Windows, why not nuget too ?)
https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8356 (update nuget for .net core, update OS for .net framework)

Comment: Which NuGet package would you update for .NET Framework?

Comment: When I open my packages.config, I see a lot of System.* package, but for the .net Framework there are never vulnerability on package version like .net core ?.

Comment: If you have a full Framework Application and you are having lots of System.* packages via NuGet, you (or people that write nuget packages that you use) are doing something wrong.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/ is usable with Full Framework, with webjob application for example.

Comment: That package is a prime example of "if you use this AND .NET Full Framework you are doing something wrong". All that is in there is already available in the full framework. Adding it to your project *again* has a high chance of being a mistake.

Comment: It is an security recommandation? Have you any source or reason ?

Comment: No, it's just pointless. You include stuff you already *have* with the full .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full .NET Framework at it's core does not *have* NuGet packages. It's one block of Framework that you got with your operating system. You can write a fully functional program without a single package. So if there is a vulnerability, you have to update this block that comes with your operating system.

.NET Core is a huge collection of NuGet packages at it's core. It does not come installed as one huge block. So you can update only a few packages. There is nothing that would come with the operating system that you could update.

Comment: Why Microsoft not communicate on vulnerability on Nuget usable with full .NET Framework ?, and that is not updated with OS update...

Comment: Do you have an example? As a generic answer I'd say "because Microsoft assumes you take only what you need and if you take more (i.e. use .NET Standard packages with full .NET Framework despite the fact those classes already exist in the framework) it's your own responsibility. But I'm open to looking at a specific example.

Comment: My first example https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-8421/, is update windows but not dll. the vulnerability does not concerne dll embeded with the deployed project ?

Comment: Which dll would that be? Did you build an installer for a .NET project? Where any dlls in there that belonged to the .NET Framework? Again, .NET Framework is a full installer for the client operating system. It does not require you to deploy the dlls with your application that are part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: This answer only covers general scenarios. However, assume ASP.NET MVC (ASP,NET 4.x) has a security issue, it would comes both Windows updates and NuGet package updates.

Comment: @ArDumez it really depends on what assemblies the patch goes into, and how that assemblies come to the final deployment machine. If the assemblies are in .NET installation folder/GAC, Microsoft ships Windows updates. If they are via Microsoft NuGet packages (ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core for instance), Microsoft ships NuGet package updates.